# nextTick error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble understanding the error,

```
Server running at 204.232.212.213 on port 8124

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
at errnoException (net.js:646:11)
at Array.0 (net.js:732:28)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)

the code is as follows:
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res){
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
 }).listen(8124, "204.232.212.213");
console.log('Server running at 204.232.212.213 on port 8124')
```

Please help me with the following, new to javascript and node.js

Comment: `Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL`

Comment: how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Make the address available.  You probably have something else using that port.

Comment: solved it by using local address 127.0.0.1 and port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

solved by using local address 0.0.0.0 and port 8000

Comment: That will prevent your Node app from being accessible from other machines, though. Just leave out the IP-number argument, or use `0.0.0.0` instead.